# ExtJS 4 - How to upload a file using a menu item

Tags: javascript, extjs, file-upload

I want to add a menu item **File Upload** button that takes in data from a CSV file and parses it out. I have a form as a menu item in a `menu.js` file that is supposed to call a method in the main controller.

However I get the following error`listener.fireFn is undefined` error, telling me that the `onAttachmentsAddClick` function is not defined.

How do I call a function after a file's been submitted?

[image: Menu]

**Code from menu**

```
...
}, {
   xtype: 'form',
   itemId: 'item_formAdd',
   border: false,
   items: [{
     buttonText: 'File Upload',
     xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
     name: 'excelFile',
     buttonOnly: true,
     hideLabel: true,
     allowBlank: false,
     clearOnSubmit: false,
     listeners: {
         'change': 'onAttachmentsAddClick'
      },
     tooltip: 'Upload Excel Template'
     }]
   }]
```

**Code from Controller**

```
...
onAttachmentsAddClick: function (button) {
   alert('onAttachmentsAddClick');
},
...
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code for both controller and view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a method called `submit` on `form` after submit the file to upload.

```
form.submit({
                url: 'http://example.xyz/csv-upload.php',
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your csv...',
                success: function(fp, o) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your photo "' + o.result.file + '" has been uploaded.');
                }
            });
```